# textview resets every time i come back to the app

Tags: android, textview, reset, foreground

Im new in android development and I have to do an application that checks for the app running in foreground, and it should update a textview with the name of the apps. For the moment Im using a string, cause i cant reference a non final variable from the runnable inner class.

I have placed my code into a Runnable class into the oncreate method of my main activity, dont know if it is the right place to put it since I want to run that once, and then let the thread do his job with an infinite loop.

One of the several problems I found is when I run my application, every time i come back to the app, the textview is empty, then the thread begins to fill it with my string, but when i left the app and come back again, is empty.

How can i keep the contents of the textview?

I put my code here, thanks for the help.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (!bExecuted)
    {
        bExecuted = true;

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView myText = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.my_view);
        final ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

        Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {

                 String foregroundTaskAppName = "";
                 String foregroundTaskAppNameOld = "";

                 while (true) 
                 {
                     try
                     {
                         Thread.sleep(500);
                        // The first in the list of RunningTasks is always the foreground task.
                        RunningTaskInfo foregroundTaskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0);

                        String foregroundTaskPackageName = foregroundTaskInfo .topActivity.getPackageName();

                        PackageInfo foregroundAppPackageInfo;

                        foregroundAppPackageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(foregroundTaskPackageName, 0);

                        foregroundTaskAppNameOld = foregroundTaskAppName;
                        foregroundTaskAppName = foregroundAppPackageInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();

                        if (!foregroundTaskAppNameOld.equals(foregroundTaskAppName))
                        {
                            myText.post(new Runnable() { 
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    String textOld = (String)myText.getText();
                                    myText.setText(textOld + "hol\n");
                                }
                            });
                        }

                    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                  }
             }
        };

        Thread myThread = new Thread(myRunnable);
        myThread.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: If You mean with "come back" that You just pause Your app, then You have to do this stuff also in onRestart I think. But if You close the app, You can store the last String for example in sharedPreferences

Answer (score 0):

What you need is proper lifecycle management, Activity goes into pause state when it is moved out of action, what you need is activity recreation when it comes back again.

As you are new to android, rather then providing implemented code, i would suggest you to read about it here in [Adnroid Developer](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) in this way you will learn more, if you are not able to even after reading suggested link, do let me know back i will assist.

Comment: it says  "In order for the Android system to restore the state of the views in your activity, each view must have a unique ID, supplied by the android:id attribute". That means that if my textview has an id i dont have to do nothing?. Thanks

Comment: If it has an ID, android will restore it. but to preserve the values such as object and other processed data you need to use APIS such as saveInstanceState and restoreInstanceState.

Comment: i got one problem, onSaveInstanceState is not called when the user simply press back in the tablet. Which event can i use&

Answer (score 0):

Once a TextView is changed it is not saved after you app gets killed.
what you need is to use Android's saved state, or use this:

```
save value:
sharedpreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("Name Your data Base", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
sp.edit().putString("NameOfVar" , "value").commit();

load value: 
sharedpreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("Name Your data Base", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String loadedValue = sp.getString("NameOfVar" , "Default Value");
```

Good Luck!

Comment: cant find the putString method in sharedpreferences. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Sorry, its sp.edit().putString("NameOfVar" , "value").commit();